# Cambiar dinámicamente un texto en una página responsive

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy programando una página responsive pero necesito tener diferentes textos dependiendo del tamaño de la misma. Es decir:

- 900px: Asociación Autónoma del Automovilismo;
- 450px: Asoc. Autónoma Automovilismo;
- <400px: AAA;

¿Tendría que cargarlos todos y mostrarlos con `display: block` y ocultarlos con `hidden`? ¿O hay una manera más eficiente?

Comment: con php no vas a poder cambiar un texto dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla. De eso se encarga CSS (más en concreto las media queries), y si necesitas más ayuda, javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mi me gusta mas así:

```css
.texto_responsive:before{
  content: attr(data-desktoptext);
}

@media (max-width:900px) {
    .texto_responsive:before {
        content: attr(data-tablettext);
    }
}

@media (max-width:400px){
    .texto_responsive:before {
        content: attr(data-phonetext);
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="texto_responsive" data-desktoptext="Asociación Autónoma del Automovilismo" data-tablettext="Asoc. Autónoma Automovilismo" data-phonetext="AAA"></span><br>
<span class="texto_responsive" data-desktoptext="Mi texto para desktop" data-tablettext="Mi texto para tablet" data-phonetext="Mi texto para movil"></span>
```

Son 2 las ventajas:

1. Puedes cambiar el texto en el html y así tener varios idiomas
2. Puedes hacerlo genérico y usarlo en mas casos

Comment: No sabía que se podían usar atributos dentro del content. Muy buena respuesta +1

Comment: Muy buena idea, sobre todo me gusta que el mismo CSS serviría para múltiples casos. Aun así sigo pensando que se debería poner el texto principal dentro de la etiqueta y después usar la técnica de @Error404 o esta.

Comment: No sabía que se podía hacer esto, muchas gracias. Tengo una duda adicional. ¿Cómo lo uso con queries de mySQL? ¿O puedo hacer trampa? Es decir: ¿content: $texto1? Gracias, lo probaré cuando tenga un tiempo. Pero me gusta.

Answer (score 6):

## Ejemplo CSS

Esto lo puedes realizar simplemente con `CSS` con la propiedad [`content`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/content), el selector [`:before`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:before) y [`media-queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

Aquí está tu ejemplo:

```css
#texto:before{
  content: "Asociación Autónoma del Automovilismo";
}

@media (max-width:900px) and (min-width:450px) {
    #texto:before {
        content: "Asoc. Autónoma Automovilismo";
    }
}

@media (max-width:400px){
    #texto:before {
        content: "AAA";
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="texto"></span>
```

---

## Ejemplo Javascript

Además, esto también lo puedes realizar mediante `Javascript` puro. ¿Cual es la principal ventaja? Que hay muchas herramientas que acceden directamente al DOM de la página (HTML) y por lo tanto con el primer ejemplo estas aplicaciones no van a poder acceder a los textos. Sin embargo, `Javascript` modifica directamente el DOM de la página y por lo tanto estas herramientas si que van a poder acceder a estos textos.

Ejemplo con `Javascript`:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", cambiarTexto);

function cambiarTexto() {    
    var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    
    if (width < 900 && width > 450){
      document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Autónoma Automovilismo";
    }else if(width < 400){
      document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "AAA";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Asociación Autónoma del Automovilismo";
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="texto">Asociación Autónoma del Automovilismo</span>
```

Comment: Una idea ingeniosa, me gusta. El problema es que si el texto es relevante debería estar en el HTML. Quiza se podría poner "Asociación Autónoma del Automovilismo" en el HTML y ocultarlo por CSS, si se desactivan los estilos aparerecerá el texto

Comment: @blonfu Se podrían crear tres spans e ir mostrando la visibilidad de cada uno de ellos. Sin embargo, creo que de esta manera tanto el HTML como el CSS quedarán mucho más limpios.

Comment: Sí, por eso planteo la idea de ponerlo en el HTML y ocultarlo pero usar tu técnica del `:before` para mostrar los textos. Y si se desactivan los estilos aparecerá el texto original y los lectores de pantalla tambien lo leerán sin problema.

Comment: @blonfu ¿Te refieres a poner un texto por defecto por si se desactivan los estilos?

Comment: Exacto, y para lectores de pantalla, buscadores, etc., que leen el HTML y no el CSS

Comment: @blonfu He creado un ejemplo con Javascript para que modifique el DOM y las herramientas que acceden directamente al DOM puedan acceder a los textos también.

Comment: @ArmandoGarcía Mira el nuevo edit con la adaptación a Javascript.

Comment: Hola @ArmandoGarcía, ¿has tenido algún problema con mi solución?

Answer (score 1):

Yo me plantearía seriamente si es necesario variar el texto. Creo que es mejor ser minimalista en las alteraciones. Por eso siempre que fuera posible eligiría una de las 3 opciones para todas las versiones.

Si escogemos el acrónimo podemos usar la etiqueta HTML correspondiente que además nos da la posibilidad de consultar el significado del acrónimo:

```
<acronym title="Asociación Autónoma del Automovilismo">AAA</acronym>
```

Y en caso de que fuera absolutamente necesario mostrar textos diferentes optaría por la opción de usar varios DIV y esconder los que no querramos mostrar. Me parece mejor para SEO, los indexadores te reconocerán los textos, fácil de implementar y no le veo inconvenientes. No debería aumentar mucho el tamaño de la página.